# validation for data (select option) from database

Tags: php

im trying to make the validation for the select option. tried with using disabled but the first data is displayed as the first choice. how can i used validation here but not with the data as the first choice but "Select Type". for input i just used class required="form-control". how about select option?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="vehicleType">Vehicle Type:</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">   
  <select class="form-control required" name="vehicleType" >
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select Type</option>
    <?php                                      
      $res=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from vehicletype where status_vehicleType='1'");
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType'];?>><?php echo $row['vehicle_Type'];?></option>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </select>                         
</div>
```

[image]

disabled skip the "select type" option and display the first data.

Comment: Try to add selected="selected" attribute in your select element

Comment: didnt worked..nothing happen.. :(

Comment: Ok then try to set value to 0 or whatever

Comment: thanks..already solved it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `selected` attribute to first `<option>` tag inside while loop.

Comment: selected=" " ??

Comment: Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="vehicleType">Vehicle Type:
  </label>
 <div class="col-sm-5">   
<select class="form-control" name="vehicleType" required >
 <option value="">Select Type</option>
 <?php                                      
   $res=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from vehicletype where status_vehicleType='1'");
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
 ?>
  <option value=<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType'];?>><?php echo $row['vehicle_Type'];?></option>
 <?php
   }
 ?>
</select>
```

this worked for me. i just get rid the disabled and only put  "required" in the attributes element without any "=" " ". didnt know required also works with this one.